# How to troubleshoot USB problems with my computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

I'm having the following problem with my personal computer:

Having the following USB Devices connected:

- Logitech wireless keyboard & mouse.
- Jabra Evolve 20 headset.
- Atheros AR9271 wireless network adapter.
- Logitech webcam C920.
- Operating system: Windows 10

When using Microsoft Teams while enabling the webcam, all USB devices including the webcam itself, get briefly disconnected. I haven't identified a specific pattern of failure, it happens sometimes even without enabling the webcam. This problem does not happen with other conference software (i.e. zoom) but it happens even out of calls.

I'm not pretty much familiar with troubleshooting hardware problems in Windows, so I'd like some ideas of where to search for possible solution.

Comment: Try a USB powered hub for the headset and webcam.

Comment: Absolutely I would try. But I'm more interested in troubleshooting the issue in order to discard driver or OS issues.